# How to install pyregion under python 3.9.6 and MacOS Sonoma 14.3.1

Tags: python, astronomy

I am trying to install **pyregion** (a package related to astronomical data analysis) under python 3.9.6 and MacOS Sonoma 14.3.1.

I have tried various ways but always encounter new obstacles.
After the standard method:
**pip3 install pyregion**
which fails with an error message
*"Failed building wheel for pyregion".*
and after trying many other suggestions found here on stackoverflow, including upgrading numpy, upgrading pip3 itself, and also
**python3 -m pip install pyregion**

I am now trying the direct installation of the files, which can be found here:
https://pypi.org/project/pyregion/#files

The first obstacle to running
`python3 setup.py install`
was:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/claudiopedrazzi/Downloads/pyregion-2.2.0/setup.py", line 5, in <module>
    from Cython.Build import cythonize
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython'*
```

I then also installed Cython
`pip3 install --upgrade cython`

Which successfully installed cython-3.0.9 for me.
Trying again running the setup.py, I get a long error message ending with:

```
/Users/claudiopedrazzi/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:17:2: warning: "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with "          "#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-W#warnings]
#warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with " \
 ^
pyregion/_region_filter.c:18264:3: error: incompatible pointer to integer conversion returning 'void *' from a function with result type 'int' [-Wint-conversion]
  import_array();
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/claudiopedrazzi/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1558:151: note: expanded from macro 'import_array'
#define import_array() {if (_import_array() < 0) {PyErr_Print(); PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ImportError, "numpy.core.multiarray failed to import"); return NULL; } }
                                                                                                                                                      ^~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/15.0.0/include/stddef.h:89:16: note: expanded from macro 'NULL'
#  define NULL ((void*)0)
               ^~~~~~~~~~
1 warning and 1 error generated.
error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
```

I would really need step by step instructions. My environment is up to date and I don't understand why this particular package gives these problems, while other packages like astropy and matplotlib work perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably put in a request with the maintainers to fix that.  I was able to reproduce the issue easily.  It looks like they've fallen behind on on keeping up with the environments.

**I am going to assume the code was written correctly, which may not be the case.  The maintainers need to address this.  You may have issues if there is indeed a bug.**  With that in mind, I was able to get past the "error: incompatible pointer to integer conversion" by adding the `-Wno-int-conversion` compiler flag when installing, which tells the compiler this conversion is actually OK.

```
CFLAGS="-Wno-int-conversion" pip install pyregion
```

For completeness, I did this work using virtual environments.  I do not expect that to matter.